# How to find the PMF of a discrete random variable that is a function of another random variable and a positive number?

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions, random-variables

X is a geometric random variable with parameter p and m is a positive integer. How can I find the PMF of the random variable max{X, m} and min{X,m}? Someone please help!!

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: consider the three cases: $$\mathsf P(\max\{X,m\}=k) = \begin{cases}  &:& k<m\\  &:& k= m\\  &:& k> m\end{cases}$$

Comment: Y = f(X) = X if X > m, Y = f(X) = m if X<= m. since X is a geometric rv, P(Y=y) = (1-p)^(x-1)p. This is what I have so far. I got stuck on the part where Y = f(X) = m if X<= m. Does m have a uniform distribution or is it just a constant? I have no idea how to find the probability distribution of m. In addition, Is there supposed to be a PMF for Y in each of the two cases or do I have to combine the PMFs in some way to get a new PMF?

Comment: $m$ is a constant; a parameter like $p$. The part where $Y=m\mbox{ if } X\leq m$ means $\mathsf P(Y=m)=\mathsf P(X\leq m)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a concrete illustration: Suppose that $X$ is geometric with parameter $p = 1/2$ and $k = 5$. Let $Y = \max\{X, 5\}$. It could happen that $X \leq 5$; if that happens, then $Y$ is just $5$. Note that you can compute the exact probability of this happening: it's $\mathbb{P}(X \leq 5) = \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 {2^2} + \frac 1 {2^3} + \frac 1 {2^4} + \frac 1 {2^5}$. This therefore yields $\mathbb{P}(Y = 5)$. On the other hand, it might hold that $X > 5$, in which case $Y = X$. For instance, we know that $\mathbb{P}(X = 10) = \frac{1}{2^{10}}$; hence, $Y = 10$ with that same probability. With this kind of analysis, you can find the probability that $Y$ is $5$, or any greater value. (This leaves only the general case to do.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got a PMF for P(Y=m) and another PMF for P(Y=X), but I'm still a little bit confused. Should I use some formula/theorem to combine those two PMFs to generate a new PMF or can I just leave the final answer like this?

Comment: The "PMF for Y" refers to a listing of all the things Y could be, along with the probabilities of it being those things. So, all you need is a full list of those values and probabilites. In the above example, Y could be 5, or 6, or 7, etc, all with probabilities you can calculate.

Comment: I still didn't quite get it. Suppose you have Y=max{7,5} and Y=max{5,7}, then for the first function, P(Y=7) = P(X=7), and for the second function, P(Y=7) = P(X<=7). What I don't understand is that there are two different probabilities associated with Y=7. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Presumably, the number $m$ is fixed; I'm using 5 just for the sake of example. There's just one probability associated with $P(Y = 7)$; the only way for $Y$ to be $7$ is if $X$ was $7$, and that has a specific calculable probability.

Comment: Ok. Does this mean that if I assign two different values to m, then I will get two distinct PMFs for Y (since m cannot take two values at the same time)? In addition, would you say the PMF for Y is piecewise since it behaves differently when X<=m compared to X>m?

Comment: Yes to both. The pmf will need to be expressed as a piecewise function, and both the cutoff location between the pieces and the values themselves will need to depend on m.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That clarified my confusion!